# Composer killed when setup laravel in Godaddy Server

Tags: php, kill, composer

I want to setup my laravel project on Godaddy server but when I am creating laravel project on Godaddy server, composer killed the process.

composer require doctrine/dbal

composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Killed

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy is probably killing processes that take up too many resources or run too long to protect their shared hosting environment.  This is behavior *may* be configured by them using [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf), which you may or may not be able to look at from your shared hosting account, depending on the permissions set.  You would not be allowed to edit these restrictions.

PHP also has its own limits, like `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time`, which may be limited by [`php.ini`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).  Your process could also be killed by PHP itself for exceeding the memory or time limit.

---

As Composer might be too resource-intensive for GoDaddy to permit you to run, you can try to resolve the dependencies on your local machine to generate a `composer.lock` file.  Once you upload that, you can run a less resource-intensive `composer install` on the GoDaddy server.

If that doesn't work, an alternative solution could be to run Composer entirely on your own machine in a similar PHP environment (same PHP version, same installed extensions) and then upload the `vendor` dependencies to your hosting account manually.

---

## Additional Resources

- Memory limit?  [composer killed while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20699258/1038828) on Stack Overflow
- Some other limit?  [composer is “killed” automatically from SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36407303/1038828) on Stack Overflow